# jquery Flexslider manual controls is not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, plugins, flexslider

I am trying to implement manual controls for the "flexslider" plugin.

Here's my code:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="columns row">
        <div class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">
            <li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: none;"><img src="1.jpg"></li>
            <li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: none;"><img src="2.jpg"></li>
            <li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: none;"><img src="3.jpg"></li>
            <li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: list-item;"><img src="4.jpg"></li>                               
        </ul><ol class="flex-control-nav"><li><a class="">1</a></li><li><a class="">2</a></li><li><a class="">3</a></li><li><a class="active">4</a></li></ol><ul class="flex-direction-nav"><li><a href="#" class="prev">Previous</a></li><li><a href="#" class="next">Next</a></li></ul></div>
    </div>


    <div class="columns row"><h2><strong>Bla bla bla</strong> Lorum lorum</h2></div>

    <div class="columns row">
    <div id="thumbnail">
        <img width="100" border="0" style="margin: 0 16px 0 0" src="1.jpg">
        <img width="100" border="0" style="margin: 0 16px 0 0" src="2.jpg">
        <img width="100" border="0" style="margin: 0 16px 0 0" src="3.jpg">
        <img width="100" border="0" style="margin: 0 16px 0 0" src="4.jpg">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="../../javascripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>

<!-- Hook up the FlexSlider -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            controlNav: true,
            manualControls: "#thumbnail img"
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to have thumbnail pictures as slider control. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you put your code into http://jsfiddle.net/ please.

Comment: @Deadlykipper Heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3h5d/

Comment: @Deadlykipper Does the fiddle help understanding my problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to add the option 'controlsContainer'.

So your jQuery code should be:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    controlsContainer: ".container",
    controlNav: true,
    manualControls: "#thumbnail img"
});
```