# jquery flexslider link to specific image

Tags: hyperlink, flexslider

is it possible to show in the flexslider a specific image, when a link from another homepage is clicked (like an anchor "www.mysite.html#slider3")? I have a page with textlinks. If the user clicks on a link like "go to slider 3", the site with flexslider appears and shows the slider 3.

Please can someone help me? I have already read this thread ([jQuery FlexSlider - Link to specific image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673212/jquery-flexslider-link-to-specific-image)) but this doesn't work for me, I don't know why.

Thanks and sorry about my bad english,
CeDe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexslider provides a property called 'startAt' which accepts an index representing the slide to display first. You can also disable the automatic playing of the slideshow by setting the 'slideshow' parameter to false. If you grab the slide reference you want to start at before you create the slideshow, you can use these parameters.

```
// create a variable to store the slide index to start at.
startAtSlideIndex = 0;

// see if a tab anchor has been included in the url
if (window.location.hash != '') {

  // Set the startAtSlideIndex variable to one less than the ordinal passed
  // note: if you have more than 9 slides, this will fall down and you'll
  //       have to do some more complex string manipulation.
  //       A querystring variable might be easier, especially if you use
  //       someone else's url parser ;)
  // Important: assumes the format of the hash is '#tabN' where N is the digit we want.
  startAtSlideIndex = window.location.hash.substr(4,1)-1;
}

$("#flexslider-container").flexslider({

  // other flexslider params

  // set the flexslider startAt param to the value of the startAtSlideIndex variable
  startAt: startAtSlideIndex

});
```

EDIT: I forgot that the location object has a 'hash' property in my original answer.

Comment: Hi Michael,

thanks for your answer! Apologies that I answer so late. Since this is not my main job, I could not even test it. Now I'll make up for it and report me again. I have a question about your code: what means the "(4,1)"?

Unfortunately I have more than 9 slides ... what do I have to change the code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wow! It works great! Thank you again! I tried it with only a few images, but now I want to make it work with more than 9 images. Please can you tell me what I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

it's me again :-)  It seems that it works for more than 9 slides too: I just changed the code a bit:
    `// Important: assumes the format of the hash is '#tabNN' where NN is the digit we want. startAtSlideIndex = window.location.hash.substr(4,2)-0;`
 Thanks and greetings!